# Проблема с установкой python пакета bip-utils(ed25519_blake2b)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Мне требуется установить пакет bip-utils.
В его зависимости входит пакет ed25519_blake2b.
Как раз таки его не получается установить

Вот сама ошибка:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: ed25519-blake2b
  Building wheel for ed25519-blake2b (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      copying src\ed25519\keys.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      copying src\ed25519\test_ed25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      copying src\ed25519\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      copying src\ed25519\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b/_version.py
      set build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b/_version.py to '1.4'
      running build_ext
      building 'ed25519_blake2b._ed25519' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ed25519-blake2b
  Running setup.py clean for ed25519-blake2b
Failed to build ed25519-blake2b
Installing collected packages: ed25519-blake2b
  Running setup.py install for ed25519-blake2b ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for ed25519-blake2b did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\121pr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      copying src\ed25519\keys.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      copying src\ed25519\test_ed25519.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      copying src\ed25519\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      copying src\ed25519\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b
      UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b/_version.py
      set build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\ed25519_blake2b/_version.py to '1.4'
      running build_ext
      building 'ed25519_blake2b._ed25519' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> ed25519-blake2b

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Пробовал устанавливать Microsoft C++ Build Tools, как и написано в ошибке.
Это не помогло

Python: 3.10.6 64 bit |
pip: 22.3 |
setuptools: 65.5.0 |
wheel: 0.37.1

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is because the package ed25519-blake2b requires Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater to build the extension. To resolve this issue, you need to install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools.

Follow these steps to install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools:

```
Go to the Visual Studio download page: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
Download the Build Tools installer by clicking on the "Download Build Tools" button.
Run the installer, and during installation, make sure the "C++ Build Tools" option is checked. Also, make sure to install the required components for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019 (which includes the C++ 14.0 compiler).
Complete the installation process.
```

After the installation is complete, open a new command prompt and try installing the package again:

bash

pip install ed25519-blake2b

If you still encounter issues during the installation, you might need to configure the environment variables for the build tools. Make sure the build tools' path is added to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, Ваш ответ на русский язык.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)